# Try-Catch block throws You cannot call a null -valued expression

Tags: powershell, try-catch, powercli

New user here so happy to be part of the site.

I have a pshell script where I invoke a rest method.

The rest call is successful however I get non-terminating errors in console that say the catch variable cannot be null.

Here is the block:

```
Function CallingREST($URL,$Body) {

$headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/xml";"Authorization"="Basic YWRtaW46ZGVmYXVsdA=="}

try {Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Body $Body -Method Post -ContentType Application/xml } 

catch { $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
                    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
                    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
                    write-host $responseBody } 
 }
```

The error I get is:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\rough\script.ps1:170 char:21
+             catch { $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What am i doing wrong. Interesting thing is this didnt happen before unsure why it started - the script executes fine.

Comment: check `$_.Exception` with `get-member` to see if it even has a response property, i would guess it doesnt, and if it has it is null. also please explain what you are trying to achieve in your catch statement

Comment: Thank you for your time - With the catch I am trying to get any errors or issues that would cause the try block to fail. In my code snipped - if the rest call fails i want to catch and display to user. Hope this helps

Comment: In that case use the exception property like suggested by swonkie

Answer (score 0):

Your Exception's response property is null. Just use

```
catch { $_.Exception}
```

Although it's not clear from your example if you even should catch this exception or let PowerShell handle it.

Also generally don't use Write-Host, just output your string or variable like so

```
"Foo"
$bar = "bar"
$bar
```